# Curve straight connection path to selected points using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I'm looking for a solution for connecting orange random points (orange color) diagonally but I used shortest path node and it seems that connects along main mesh's edges instead. Is there another to create a web out of those points ?
[image]
[image]
[image][image]
[image]

World map picture made B&W from the original alpha channel:

[image: BW World Map]

Blender file (without the world map picture): [image]

Comment: I do not understand what is your condition to connect two orange spheres. Proximity ? Defining a short/long path ? Random walk ?

Comment: I don't how to describe the condition but i hope you can help me starting from my description of what i'm expecting to happen: here we go... From all the points on globe i select just a few / many by a selection method; Those selected points i want to connect by some kind shortest route that i will call it directly route. A directly route that makes a straight curve line connecting the nearest selected points but NOT following mesh edges as you can see in picture above but instead creating its own route directly to the points making a kind of  triangles web connection.

Comment: Sure, in case you need to view the source I let you the .blend file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqJ28qgtNvgxjL1g15d0eWvpfZLzSw?e=87ffav

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ instead of MS services that require identification ? You will get a link that you then copy/paste in the description of your question (not as a comment please).

Comment: here you go, https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=b4ExeekN

Comment: The earth image is not pack in your blend file. Could you add it and upload again?

Comment: my bad and thank you for your patience. Here it is just the image: https://we.tl/t-s8NWT5NZgp . It should work if you put it back into image texture node.

Comment: Looks like a job for [Points to Curve](https://imgur.com/a/KVE5rbj) ? Especially bearing in mind you can split your points into groups, by, say, mesh island, or Voronoi...

Comment: I edited the question to include the image, as the provided link expires after 7 days. The alpha channel file being 2Mb, I converted it to B&W instead to fit under imgur limit.